# Write a query to display last 3 low salary?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
  SELECT DISTINCT salary
    FROM worker a
   WHERE 3 >= (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT salary)
                 FROM worker b
                WHERE a.salary >= b.salary)
ORDER BY salary DESC
```

Can anyone explain this Query?

Comment: Can anyone explain the above query???

Comment: what do you mean by telling `last`, the lowest 3 ..?

Answer (score 3):

Here is your query, formatted nicely:

```
SELECT DISTINCT salary
FROM Worker a
WHERE 3 >= (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT salary) FROM Worker b WHERE a.salary >= b.salary)
ORDER BY
    salary DESC;
```

For each worker in your table, the subquery is finding the count/number of workers whose distinct salary is *greater* than the salary of the worker in the outer query.  Only works for whom there are three or fewer other workers with a greater distinct salary will be returned by the query.

There is another way of writing your query, using analytic functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT salary
FROM
(
    SELECT salary, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) dr
    FROM Worker
) t
WHERE dr <= 3;
```

EDIT:

The simplest way to write the query in Oracle is:

```
select salary
from (select distinct salary
      from worker
      order by salary
     ) s
where rownum <= 3
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display last 3 low salary than you can also write it as

`select top 3 * from Worker order by salary asc`

Comment: yeah for oracle you can use `ROWNUM`

Comment: But it will return the same output as asked in the question.@GordonLinoff